# How can one allow or deny an ssh login for a specific user(s) or group(s) on an sshd server?

Tags: linux, ssh, login, authorization

**How can one allow or deny an ssh login for a specific user(s) or group(s) on an sshd server?**

(I realize SE has similar questions, but not I could find any that address this specific point. All others I found appear to conflate other scenarios.)

Answer (score 3):

### Update the sshd config

To ***deny*** a user ssh login, add this to the end of your sshd config file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in Linux/Unix/BSD):

`DenyUsers theusername`

For groups:

`DenyGroups thegroupname`

### Restart the sshd service

Then restart the `sshd` service. The following works on Ubuntu 18.04:

`systemctl restart sshd`

### More details

One can add a space-separated list of user or group names, respectively.

The `AllowUsers` and `AllowGroups` directives do the opposite.

Excerpt from the [sshd_config man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config):

> **DenyGroups**
>
> This keyword can be followed by a list of group name
>   patterns, separated by spaces. Login is disallowed for users whose
>   primary group or supplementary group list matches one of the patterns.
>   Only group names are valid; a numerical group ID is not recognized. By
>   default, login is allowed for all groups. The allow/deny directives
>   are processed in the following order: **DenyUsers**, **AllowUsers**,
>   **DenyGroups**, and finally **AllowGroups**.
>
> **DenyUsers**
>
> This keyword can be followed by a list of user name
>   patterns, separated by spaces. Login is disallowed for user names that
>   match one of the patterns. Only user names are valid; a numerical user
>   ID is not recognized. By default, login is allowed for all users. If
>   the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST are separately
>   checked, restricting logins to particular users from particular hosts.
>   The allow/deny directives are processed in the following order:
>   **DenyUsers**, **AllowUsers**, **DenyGroups**, and finally **AllowGroups**.
>
> See *PATTERNS* in [ssh_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)(5) for more information on patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is by using access.conf.

First, you need to enable pam_access in ***/etc/pam.d/sshd*** by adding the following line:

`required pam_access.so`

Then you can edit ***/etc/security/access.conf***, and remove access to the required user(s)/group(s) by adding the following line for each one:

`-:<user or group>:ALL`